# SpringBoot2 + Spring security CORS OPTIONS method return 401 code

Tags: angular, spring, spring-security, cors, spring-security-oauth2

I use `Angular` + `Spring Boot2` + `Spring Security`. I created `WebMvcConfigurer` config for allow `CORS`:

```
@Component
@Profile("dev")
class DevWebMvcConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**").allowedMethods(ALL);
        registry.addMapping("/oauth/token").allowedMethods(ALL);
    }
}
```

And create security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/security/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().permitAll()
                .and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

But, When I try make request from angular:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 401
```

I get 401 error code. How can I fix this? All the examples I've found boil down to writing a filter like this:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        if (HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name().equalsIgnoreCase(((HttpServletRequest) req).getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

But this is some kind of shit. We set the status for all `OPTIONS` requests that everything is OK. What is it?

My `DevWebMvcConfigurer` is created only when the profile is `dev`. How do I add `OPTIONS` requests permission to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `/oauth/token` to the config.

```
        http.cors().and().authorizeRequests()
                // add the "/oauth/token" permitAll
                .antMatchers("/login", "/security/**","/oauth/token").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().permitAll()
                .and().csrf().disable();
```